# Netbeans External Console error: "sh:/cygdrive/c/Users/me/AppData/local/Temp/.../...termexec.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, netbeans

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world program in c++ using netbeans(in windows 10), however I'm getting the following error:

**sh:/cygdrive/c/Users/myuser~1/AppData/local/Temp/dlight_-2128187438/8c9e2533/dlight5897405347450711582termexec.sh: No such file or directory**

Press [Enter] to close terminal ...

If I use the inetrnal terminal I can actually run the program but when I change to external I recieve this error. I don't know if its a cygwin problem or a configuration problem.

Comment: Some people are still looking for an answer, it would be nice to give feedback on the posted answer and/or share with the community how you solved the issue (in case you did it yourself).

Comment: Please consult: [NetBeans termexec.sh error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54983847/2396883)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked to switch the External Terminal Type (Project Properties → Run) from Default to Command Window.

Comment: Didn't work for me. And this error seems to happen randomly. If i just wildly press Run again and again, sometimes it works and sometimes doesn't :/