# Error when using Netbeans External Console

Tags: c++, c++11, netbeans

I'm trying to compile a simple hello world program in c++ using netbeans 8.2 (in windows 10), however I'm getting the following error:

[image: Error]

[image: External Terminal and Command Window]

[image: Compiler PATH]

If I use the internal terminal I can actually run the program but when I change to external I receive this error.

I already tried to change **External Terminal Type** from "Default" to "Command Window" without success...

My project location is very simple: **C:/NetBeansProject/Test** (I also tried a lot of locations without success...)

Comment: There is an answer in [Netbeans External Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42216334/netbeans-external-console-error). However, nobody gave feedback for that...

Comment: I tried and it doesn't work...

Comment: Please update your question with a screen shot of the Output window in NetBeans containing the error when you run the program with these settings: _Console Type = External Terminal_ and _External Terminal Type = Command Window_.

Comment: @skomisa Thank you for your reply. Updated my post!

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't offer an explicit solution for your problem, but since this works for me the following information may be helpful anyway:

- I am also using NetBeans 8.2 with C++ 11 on Windows 10, so you probably have a configuration issue. Therefore I will show my settings on several relevant screens and perhaps you can resolve the problem yourself by comparing your configuration with mine.
- Here is my **Run** configuration (**{project} > Properties > Run**) for the C++ project:
  [image]
  I tested using both the **Debug** and **Release** configurations with no problems.
- I don't think it's relevant but here is the output from doing clean/build for the project:

  cd 'D:\NB82\CppApplication_3'
  C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug clean
  "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .clean-conf
  make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFytZ.png): Entering directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'
  rm -f -r build/Debug
  make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'

  CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 457ms)
  cd 'D:\NB82\CppApplication_3'
  C:\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
  "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
  make.exe[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFytZ.png): Entering directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'
  "/C/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_3.exe
  make.exe[2]: Entering directory`/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'
  mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW-Windows
  rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d"
  g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o main.cpp
  mkdir -p dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows
  g++     -o dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/cppapplication_3 build/Debug/MinGW-Windows/main.o 
  make.exe[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tR0K.png): Leaving directory `/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'
  make.exe[1]: Leaving directory`/d/NB82/CppApplication_3'

  BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1s)
- This shows the NetBeans screen for my simple *"Hello World!"* project, and the terminal window produced by running the project (**F6**):

  [image: NetBeans window]
- This show the **Build Tools** settings for C++ (**Tools > Options > C++ > Build Tools** tab):

  [image: OptionsCpp]

If none of that helps, here are a couple more things to check:

- If you are using **MinGW**, do you have **C:\MinGW\bin** included in your **PATH** environment variable?
- Update your question if the NetBeans log contains any unexpected errors (**View > IDE Log**).

Finally, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53038764/2985643) mentions having your problem because..

> ...the folder name in the project path was the reason. Try to change
>   location of your project to something simple, like
>   "c:\NetBeansProjects\prj1".

It's worth spending 2 minutes trying that since the path to my project is very simple, and yours is not.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I have all my settings same as you but it didn't work... I tried to reinstall Netbeans several times, tried Netbeans 8.1, 8.2, Developer, without success...

Comment: @RodrigoSargaço OK. What is the absolute path of your project's folder? Also, did you try creating another project with a simple path?

Comment: Some wierd thing happened. I have 2 computers (desktop and laptop) and both had the problem. I tried Netbeans on my Desktop and it works (I didnt change anything! Like magic.) but my Laptop is not working.... (I use my laptop for work :( )

Comment: @RodrigoSargaço OK, very strange. If this is still unresolved I can only suggest that you compare your two NetBeans instances to see what is configured differently in the one that fails, but I'm sure you have already done that. The root cause is that long file path shown in your screen shot of the terminal window but I have no idea what is causing it. Are both computers using Windows 10?

Answer (score 0):

My students also have this problem.
There are some situations that can originate this problem (special characters in the username, antivirus, folders with cloud synchronization, ... ). However, for now (without changing NetBeans source code) the only justification that I can present it is related with timeouts when NetBeans is starting a new process (after line 244 in [TerminalLocalNativeProcess.java](https://github.com/doriancuentasback/nbp-resources/blob/master/main-silver/dlight.nativeexecution/src/org/netbeans/modules/nativeexecution/TerminalLocalNativeProcess.java))
Please try the following patch to minimize the problems: [NBPatch](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rg6uweJPkms2zN4K3rU0epewMP9RLjOx)

Good luck! :-p

Comment: it´s currently 2021 and it seems this issue is happening since 2018. I came here to say that the only way I found on internet so far to fix the issue is running the NBPatch as mentioned by @androidtester.

I'm curious to know what the .exe file does, but in fact this is the only thing that fixed the problem.

Before running the patch, I found that netbeans was only creting a kind of ...termexec.sh.res file, So after running the patch, netbeans now creates three files in  dlight_user folder (...termexec, ...termexec.sh and ...termexec.sh.res). Problem fixed (patched). THANKS A LOT.

Comment: I have the same problem with the new version of netbeans 19, when I switch to external terminal and windows command it gives error. Is there another way to inter values using scanf please ?